# npm run build is not working, trying to manually upload build to netlify

Tags: react-native

I attempted to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWXApOO_Nng
I want to update my build on netlify, and this seems to be the most straight forward way. Running "netlify deploy --dir dist" uploads a build onto netlify but it doesn't included my updated code. So, I tried running npm run build to attempt to get a build folder like the person in the video and upload my website manually, I got this error below. I researched and experimented with entry points and setting up the webpack mode, but nothing seemed to work or just made it more complicated and didn't address the problem. What can I try next?

```
PS C:\Users\jacks\Standle> npm run build

standle@1.0.0 build

webpack

assets by status 0 bytes [cached] 1 asset

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 
'production' for this value.      
Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable 
defaults for each environment.    
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. 
Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\jacks\Standle'

resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\jacks\Standle'
using description file: C:\Users\jacks\Standle\package.json (relative path: .)

Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
using description file: C:\Users\jacks\Standle\package.json (relative path: ./src)

  no extension

    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    C:\Users\jacks\Standle\src doesn't exist
  .js

    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    C:\Users\jacks\Standle\src.js doesn't exist
  .json

    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    C:\Users\jacks\Standle\src.json doesn't exist
  .wasm

    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    C:\Users\jacks\Standle\src.wasm doesn't exist
  as directory

    C:\Users\jacks\Standle\src doesn't exist

webpack 5.90.1 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 246 ms
```

I expect to have a /react-deploy folder like the person in the video which has a build folder I can drag and drop into the netlify website. I've tried setting up a webpack.config.js file and redirecting the entry point, but that research led me down a rabbit hole that didn't seem to have anything to do with generating a build folder.